# How to make WPF TextBox with a scrollbar automatically scroll to the bottom when lines are added?

Tags: .net, wpf, scroll

For example like Visual Studio's "Output" window does.

Is there a way to do it in XAML?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can handle the TextChanged event, which will fire whenever you change that TextBox's Text:
[`TextBoxBase.ScrollToEnd()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.scrolltoend.aspx).

Answer (score 12):

There is a way to do it in XAML, you can use this Style to display it like a Console would (Be aware of the drawbacks, it just looks like a Console but does not completely behave like it)

```
        <Style x:Key="ConsoleTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                        <ScrollViewer RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                            <ScrollViewer.RenderTransform>
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1"/>
                            </ScrollViewer.RenderTransform>
                            <TextBox Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                                <TextBox.RenderTransform>
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1"/>
                                </TextBox.RenderTransform>
                            </TextBox>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

**How does it work**

Inside the TextBox, a ScrollViewer is flipped vertically (the "new" lines are added at the Bottom)

In the ScrollViewer, there is another Textbox which is flipped Vertically to display the Text correctly (not upside down).

**Using the Style**

Include it in your App.xaml or via ResourceDictionary and set the Style of the TextBox to ConsoleTextBox.

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource ConsoleTextBox}"/>
```

**Drawbacks**

- When you copy the Text from this "Console" there will be no Line Breaks.
- Scrolling with the Mouse is inverted

Comment: Definitely the right answer to specify via XAML only !

Comment: I've tried this approach, but the mouse scroll-wheel action is inverted. Is this just me? If not, what's the fix?

Comment: I guess you have to create a custom `ScrollViewer`, which handles the `OnPreviewMouseWheel(MouseWheelEventArgs e)` event, and inverts the Delta property. In my opinion this solution ends up being worse than just choosing to `ScrollToEnd()`... You still have C# codebehind, which was trying to be avoided.

Answer (score 9):

You could write an [attached property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903943%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) or even better a [behavior](http://www.wpftutorial.net/Behaviors.html) that listens to the [TextChanged event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.textchangedevent.aspx) and [scrolls to the bottom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.scrolltoend.aspx) in the callback.

Answer (score 7):

Visual Studio output window behavior is special, because it will only keep auto scrolling down if the caret is at the end of the text box, which allows you to examine the output without being disturbed if new lines are added to it.

I've got such behavior with this code

```
bool scrollToEnd = TbEvents.CaretIndex == TbEvents.Text.Length;
TbEvents.AppendText(text + Environment.NewLine);
if (scrollToEnd)
{
    TbEvents.CaretIndex = TbEvents.Text.Length;
    TbEvents.ScrollToEnd();
}
```

Comment: What is "TbEvents"?

Comment: @morknox your TextBox reference

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Textbox wrapped within a ScrollViewer, like I have mine shown below:

```xml
<ScrollViewer x:Name="ConsoleOutputScrollViewer" Background="Black">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="ConsoleOutputTextBox" TextChanged="ConsoleOutputTextBox_TextChanged"
                 Background="Transparent" Foreground="White" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="15"
                 Padding="5 0 0 0" FontFamily="Consolas" TextWrapping="Wrap" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <Grid Height="100"/>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

You can then handle the `TextChanged` Event and call `ScrollToEnd()` like mentioned in other answers here. HOWEVER, the drawback to this is that you won't be able to view the text history when a new line is added, which can present the user with a very bad experience, especially if you have new lines being added constantly.

An easy solution to this is to check and compare the current scrollviewer `VerticalOffset` to the total `ScrollableHeight` of the ScrollViewer, as shown below:

```cs
private void ConsoleOutputTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ConsoleOutputScrollViewer.VerticalOffset == ConsoleOutputScrollViewer.ScrollableHeight)
    {
        ConsoleOutputScrollViewer.ScrollToEnd();
    }
}
```