# After overriding ScrollViewer and TextBox (in WPF), the thumb of Scrollbars are not moving based on the text size of TextBox

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have Overridden default template for TextBox and ScrollViewer. Now when i am entering text in the TextBox, the thumb of the scrollbars(Vertical and Horizontal) are not automatically moving based on the text size. Below is a screenshot.
[TextBox Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4eZv.png)

The overridden template for ScrollViewer and TextBox are:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None" />
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Visible"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Visible"/>

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
                    <Border Name="Border" BorderThickness="1" Background="Black" BorderBrush="#346BAF">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Style="{DynamicResource TextBoxScrollViewer}"/>
                    </Border> 
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#222B35"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush"  Value="#696969"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#464A51"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush"  Value="#00BFFF"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

 <Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Visible"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Visible"/>
        <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="450"/>
        <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="450"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <ScrollContentPresenter Grid.Column="0"/>
                        <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="#0080FF" BorderThickness="0,1,1,0">
                            <ScrollBar Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="#0080FF" BorderThickness="1,0,0,1">
                            <ScrollBar Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Orientation="Horizontal"  Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="#0080FF" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1" Background="#2C446B"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Not quite a solution to your problem, but I suggest adding `<Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>` to your TextBox style. It will prevent the text from "escaping" outside the boundaries of the control

Comment: Actually i already tried that. But my requirement is to display both the ScrollBars by default. TextWrapping would wrap the text and my Horizontal scroll bar would not be visible. Also this issue is happening with Vertical scrollbar as well which would not get fixed using TextWrap.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you add content to the TextBox, listen to the event TextChanged. In this method, use this method: TextBoxBase.ScrollToEnd(). This will always move the scroll to the end of the text.

Comment: I have already thought in that direction as well, but my restriction here is to add only XAML code(Not supposed to modify .cs file). Also there is one more point i would like to highlight that this issue is not seen, if i don't Overload ScrollViewer. If you have any idea on how this could be fixed only using XAML, please let me know.

Comment: Try this.It has an option to achieve this in XAML only. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010462/how-to-make-wpf-textbox-with-a-scrollbar-automatically-scroll-to-the-bottom-when/7010608?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up!! But this looks like to be more of a workaround rather than fix. I am still not sure why after overloading ScrollVewer, the textbox is not able to update the scrollbars thumb. Also the solution they have provided would work fine(as well as UI look) when the value of  VerticalScrollBarVisibility and HorizontalScrollBar visibility is set as Auto as default. In my case the value is "Visible" .Since as per the code, they are rotating the ScrollBar, the issue seems to be resolved for me but I am seeing some weird UI behavior.