# In a C# application how do I create a textbox that automatically scrolls to the latest entry

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have been trying to modify an application that has a logging window that currently only scrolls if the user manually scrolls it using the mouse scroll wheel. I want the window to scroll down when it updates. I have searched pretty extensively and found many answers but none seem to work.

I am a novice when it comes to C# and .NET etc. Here is what I currently have:

**XAML:**

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
              Height="Auto" 
              Margin="10,430,0,0"
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Width="Auto"
              VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <TextBox x:Name="txtbxCommLog"
                     Height="500"
                     Text=""
                     TextWrapping="Wrap"
                     Width="1060"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

**C#**

```
public async Task AddtoLogWindow(string text)
{
    await _dispatcherQueue.EnqueueAsync(() =>
    {
        if (logText.Length > 10000)
        {
            logText = "";
        }
        logText += text;
        txtbxCommLog.Text = logText;
        scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollViewer.ActualHeight);
    });
}
```

But this approach doesn't change the content of the textbox it is always at the top.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make WPF TextBox with a scrollbar automatically scroll to the bottom when lines are added?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010462/how-to-make-wpf-textbox-with-a-scrollbar-automatically-scroll-to-the-bottom-when)

Comment: Thanks for fixing that for me. This is the first question I have ever asked. Not sure why all of the white space was removed.

Comment: I am not sure I am ok with drawbacks mentioned in the solution also it quite old. Every time I try older solutions, they seem to be out of date i e the method ScrollToEnd is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

### EDIT: UWP vs WPF

After re-reading the question, I think that you are intending to ask about Universal Windows Platform (UWP) and not Windows Presentation Framework (WPF). Both are XAML-based UI frameworks for C#, and they have very similar, but not quite the same syntax and properties. There are other XAML-based C# UI frameworks as well, such as Xamarin Forms, etc.

To get the `ScrollViewer` to work as desired in UWP, see this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41898598/15534202

```cs
private void ScrollToBottom(TextBox textBox)
{
    var grid = (Grid)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(textBox, 0);
    for (var i = 0; i <= VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(grid) - 1; i++)
    {
        object obj = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(grid, i);
        if (!(obj is ScrollViewer)) continue;
        ((ScrollViewer)obj).ChangeView(0.0f, ((ScrollViewer)obj).ExtentHeight, 1.0f, true);
        break;
    }
}
```

---

### Original Answer for WPF

I think that you just need `scrollViewer.ScrollToEnd();` instead of `ScrollToVerticalOffset`. This is working for me as shown below.

You can also achieve this without a `ScrollViewer` and simply use the TextBox as such:

### xaml

```xml
<TextBox x:Name="txtbxCommLog"
            Text="Staring text"
            TextWrapping="Wrap"
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
```

### Code Behind

```
txtbxCommLog.Text += text;
txtbxCommLog.ScrollToEnd();
```

### Result:

[image]

Using the code from the example you provided, I was able to make things work using the `ScrollViewer` as well:

### Code Behind.

Note that I use a timer to simulate the log entries...

```cs
        private Timer _timer;

        public ScrollingTextBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _timer = new Timer(500);
            _timer.Elapsed += (s, e) => AddtoLogWindow($"{ DateTime.Now}\n");
            _timer.Start();
        }

        public async Task AddtoLogWindow(string text)
        {
            await Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
            {
                //if (logText.Length > 10000)
                //{
                //    logText = "";
                //}
                //logText += text;
                txtbxCommLog.Text += text;
                scrollViewer.ScrollToEnd();
            });
        }
```

### xaml

```xml
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                      Height="Auto"
                      VerticalAlignment="Top"
                      Width="Auto"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                      <!--VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"-->
            <TextBox x:Name="txtbxCommLog"
                     Text="Staring text"
                     TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        </ScrollViewer>
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: When I try and add scrollViewer.ScrollToEnd() it is undefined. We must be on different versions, or possibly I need to add a reference to source file.

Comment: What version are you using? My posted answer works both in .Net Framework 4.8.1 and Net 8.0

Comment: @DonV, I think that the issue is you are using UWP and not WPF. Does this link help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62470672/how-can-i-scroll-to-the-end-of-a-textbox-in-uwp

Comment: I tried to use both of the suggestions and both VerticalScrollBarVisibility and ScrollToEnd. Both are undefined.

Comment: Did you try this? link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40114620/uwp-c-sharp-scroll-to-the-bottom-of-textbox  
 private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    var grid = (Grid)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(textBox1, 0); 
    for (var i = 0; i <= VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(grid) - 1; i++) 
        { 
            object obj = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(grid, i); 
            if (!(obj is ScrollViewer)) continue; 
            ((ScrollViewer)obj).ChangeView(0.0f, ((ScrollViewer)obj).ExtentHeight, 1.0f); 
            break; 
        } 
    }
}

Comment: That is a UWP solution, rather than WPF. There are several different XAML UI frameworks that C# supports. You tagged the post WPF, but it seems that you are actually using UWP. There are others as well, such as Xamarin.

Comment: Ok as I mentioned I am very new to this I inherited the app and an trying to learn my way around.  I bet You are right how would I know that for sure.

Comment: I looked at the links and made the changes based on the link you provided. Now it works. Indeed I was trying solutions for WPF and I was not using it. I will need to look at it more closely because it seems to be pretty complicated for what seems like a basic function. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Okay, glad that helped! I will update my answer accordingly. I think this is a super common issue and confusion.

Comment: @DonV, I updated my answer and added the UWP tag to the question. Please upvote and mark as accepted if it was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

I created a test project and the following worked for me:

1. Take the TextBox out of the ScrollViewer control.
2. Add VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" or VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" to the TextBox XAML.
3. Handle the TextChanged event of the TextBox.
4. Inside the TextChanged event handler, call txtbxCommLog.ScrollToEnd();

Not sure if you need the ScrollViewer or not, so this solution may not work.  But it should work if you don't actually need it.

Answer (score 0):

lets assume you have a textbox
in Xaml:

```xml
<TextBox Text="{Binding LogText}"
         VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
         IsReadOnly="True" />
```

if you have got ViewModel, then

```cs
private string _logText;

    public string LogText
    {
        get { return _logText; }
        set
        {
            if (_logText != value)
            {
                _logText = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LogText));
            }
        }
    }
   
 
// Method to add new log entries
    public void AddLogEntry(string entry)
    {
        LogText += entry + Environment.NewLine;

        // Scroll to the end of the TextBox
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LogText));
    }
```

Whenever you want to add a new entry, call the AddLogEntry method

```cs
//an instance of YourViewModel named viewModel
viewModel.AddLogEntry("New log entry");
```